# Set the default target(s) of a Makefile (GNU Make) via Environment Variable

Tags: gnu-make

I'd like to set the default target(s) of a Makefile to the space-deliminted value of an Environment Variable.

For this solution to work correctly, it must be possible for me to set an environment variable, then run `make` and have the target, (or optionally space-delimited targets), contained in the environment variable be used as though they were passed as targets.

```sh
DEFAULT_TARGETS="target target2" make
# ... should produce the same result as ...
make target1 target2
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by adding something like this to your makefile:

```
ifneq ($(DEFAULT_TARGETS),)
__default_targets: $(DEFAULT_TARGETS)
.DEFAULT_GOAL = __default_targets
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Following @Andreas lead I've landed on this ...

```
.PHONY: DEFAULT_TARGET
DEFAULT_TARGETS ?= intro
DEFAULT_TARGET: $(DEFAULT_TARGETS)
```

This use the "First Target as Default" paradigm, then expands the contents of the `DEFAULT_TARGETS` env-var to add requisites. It also has the advantage that if the `DEFAULT_TARGETS` environment variable is not set, the makefile will use the fall-back value, in this case that's `intro`.

In the shell this would look like, `DEFAULT_TARGETS="target target2" make`

Comment: Deleted my answer since multiple targets to .DEFAULT_GOAL is invalid.